# Sonar naming convention issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, sonarqube

Following is the error:

```
Rename this 'AppHeaderController' function to match the regular expression ^[a-z|$][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

There is nothing wrong in the naming as seen, still the error is seen. How to fix this?

Comment: I have many other controllers following the same naming convention styles, it is throwing only in 2 controllers including this

Comment: Can you provide examples where you have other controllers not raising such issue?

Answer (score 2):

This rule raises error when name used for function declaration doesn't comply with some pattern. So if it's usual for you to create "constructor" functions (thus they start from capital letter), you should probably change the default regular expression, e.g. `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`.